# AttributeError: module 'keras_preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'DataFrameIterator'

Tags: tensorflow, flask, tf.keras

I am following this tutorial on deploying an image classifier : [Deploying an image classification model](https://medium.com/@limwz.daniel/deploying-your-deep-learning-model-using-flask-and-docker-c05a6d1d96a5)

but am facing the above error message

> 

(venv) C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master>py app.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-11-10 22:26:47.227887: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-11-10 22:26:47.229555: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 15, in 
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2\compat_*init*_.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 34, in 
from . import compat
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2\compat\v1\compat_*init*_.py", line 39, in 
from . import v1
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1_*init*_.py", line 682, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.api.*v1 import keras
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api_*init**.py", line 10, in 
from . import keras
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api\keras_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
from . import datasets
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api\keras\datasets_*init*_.py", line 14, in 
from . import imdb
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api\keras\datasets\imdb_*init*_.py", line 11, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets.imdb import get_word_index
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets\imdb.py", line 25, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import *remove_long_seq
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing_*init**.py", line 26, in 
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
File "C:\Users\ctkay\flask_image_classifier-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 464, in 
class DataFrameIterator(image.DataFrameIterator, Iterator):
AttributeError: module 'keras_preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'DataFrameIterator'

when I try to run the app.py file in my windows 10 command shell.
What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use keras 2.2.2 and Tensorflow 2.0 version. Thanks!

Comment: did you find a work around about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Tensorflow 2.6, use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.Iterator( n, batch_size, shuffle, seed )`